# Count all record in table in yii2 without where clause

Tags: php, yii, yii2, yii2-advanced-app

I want to count all record from table without specify any condition :

now, i am doing by this way

```
$result['cms'] = Cms::find()->where([])->count();
```

and it will give me result,but i don't want to use **where** clause.

So how to count all records without **where clause.**

Thank you

Comment: $results = Cms::model()->findAll(array(*query criteria here*));
$count = count ( $results );

Comment: i  want all record  without any criteria

Comment: $records = Cms::findAll();
$count = count($records);

But if you have a so many records in table then how will you handle this ?
Because it will display all records

Comment: thank you , i want to display count  in my admin deshboard

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can see this doc http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-db-activequery.html

simply using

count(): returns the result of a COUNT query.

```
Cms::find()->count();
```

all(): returns an array of rows with each row being an associative array of name-value pairs.

```
Cms::find()->all();
```

see this guide for more  http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-db-query-builder.html